# Where can I find keys section in new developer.apple.com

Tags: ios, xcode

Can't find keys section in new UI

According to apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns it should be in developer.apple.com.

My role is developer.

[image]

Comment: @Niki Thanks. Looks like I'm in developer role. Only Account Holder or Admin can create roles.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and I see the keys section:
[image]

Which role does your account have? It would be weird but maybe you don't have the rights to see the keys? My Account has the `Administrator` role.

Comment: I have the developer role. That could be the problem

Answer (score -1):

First, you will have to create certificates and provisional profiles for your application. Only after that, you'll be able to see keys section in Apple Developer dashboard.